# How to import hardhat to this repository

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, yarnpkg, hardhat, decentralized-applications

I am working on a dApp using this repository: https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/nft-school-examples/tree/main/end-to-end I am trying to import the hardhat. I've installed it with `yarn add hardhat`. When I import the hardhat with `const _hardhat = require("hardhat")` and run `yarn start`; I get the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/undici/lib/api/api-request.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'async_hooks' in '/home/bugra/deneme/end-to-end/packages/react-app/node_modules/undici/lib/api'
```

How can I resolve this issue? How can I use hardhat within the `packages/react-app/src/components/Minter.jsx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are importing ethers make sure to import it from 'ethers' library.

I have got this issue on react, after wasting much time I realized that I was importing ethers from hardhat. After importing it from ethers everything works.